# Regular expression for matching integers inclosed within square brackets including whitespace

Tags: regex

```
s="  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx"
```

Regex match should return `[12, -43, 12]`

```
re.findall(r'\[([+-]?\d+)]', s)
```

It doesn't work. I have no idea how to include whitespace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293024/optional-whitespace-regex#comment19850655_14293041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow leading and trailing whitespaces:

```
\[\s*([+-]?\d+)\s*\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PIJ4Lx/2)

Comment: Thanks it works.The returned object does not have signs [12, 43, 12] , Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fixed to use `\s` instead of `\W`